# How to properly remove sensitive information after it was posted?

Tags: discussion, editing

Sometimes a question is posted, which contains sensitive information the OP shouldn't have shared. Most commonly it's part of a scanned image, but it can be in the message text.

In several cases ([example](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/109297/does-the-booking-service-usually-save-your-credit-card-information-and-share-it)) I saw that the OP or someone else edited the question and remvoed this information.

But the editing history remains, with the sensitive information. So editing just hides it a little.

Is there a way to properly remove sensitive information?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Flag for moderator attention and explain exactly what the issue is. Include the revision number of edited questions with such information for ease of finding.

Moderators can then purge the revision history of this information.

Avoid mentioning the presence of such information in e.g. comments, as this only serves to bring more attention it, partially defeating the purpose of removing it.

Comment: Exactly this. Flag for mod attention, explain the problem and we will react accordingly.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that it requires two moderators: one to propose the redaction, and another to approve, so it may take some time after your flag is marked "helpful" for the redaction to take place.